# return user to a view with success message after registration laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to return a view with a success message with a link to the login page after registering a user, however the session message isn't passed along with the view.

Here is my `registred()` method

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    return view('frontend.pages.register-success')->with('message', 'Your registration was successful. Click the button below to login to your account');
}
```

Here is the view page

```
@extends('frontend.layouts.main')
@section('title', 'Registration successful')
@section('content')
<!-- Main Content -->
<div id="main-content" class="site-main clearfix">

    @if (Session::has('message'))
    <section class="popup">
        <div class="popup-inner">
            <div class="popup-content">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="assets/img/popup/popup.jpg" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="content text-center">

                    <p class="">{{ Session::get('message') }}</p>

                    <h6 class="heading">REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL!</h6>

                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="button color-2 login-submit">LOGIN TO YOUR ACCOUNT</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    @endif

</div><!-- /#main-content -->
@endsection
```

Comment: You are passing the `message` as a variable, NOT a session. try `<p class="">{{ $message }}</p>`

Comment: I suggest you learn the basics of Laravel first. There are free tutorial videos of Laravel here: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch

Comment: btw, the registration system logs the user in after registration so they won't be able to get to the login page since they are already logged in at that point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use session() global helper instead of Session:

```
      // flash message create
      session()->flash('message', 'This is a message!'); 
      session()->flash('alert-class', 'alert-danger');
```

get flash message by key from your blade file

```
@if(session()->has('message'))
<section class="popup">
        <div class="popup-inner">
            <div class="popup-content">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="assets/img/popup/popup.jpg" alt="Image">
                </div>
                <div class="content text-center">

                    <p class="">{{ session('message') }}</p>

                    <h6 class="heading">REGISTRATION SUCCESSFUL!</h6>

                    <a href="{{ route('login') }}" class="button color-2 login-submit">LOGIN TO YOUR ACCOUNT</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **"laravel/ui": "^4.2"**, add this method in your controller **"RegisterController"**:

```
// ADD CUSTOM FLASH MESSAGE
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    $request->session()->flash('flash-alert', "¡Bienvenido a Winter-APP, <b>$user->name!</b> ");
}
```

Now, add this code in your file **"register.blade.php"**:

```
<div class="container">
@if(session()->has('flash-alert'))
    @php
        $alert = session()->get('flash-alert');
    @endphp
    {{--USANDO EL COMPONENTE ALERTA--}}
    <x-alerta type="success" :message="$alert"></x-alerta>
@endif
</div>
```

And the message will show :
[image]